# Adding a groupby ability to subgraph of the graph protocol

Tags: the-graph, subgraph

How would I add the aggregation and grouping to a subgraph deployed as a hosted service on thegraph protocol? The schema.graphql does not support adding a `type Query{...}` or a type object in general such as

```
type Aggregated{
  field: String!
  value: String!
}
```

When I try to add these, I am getting `Aggregated: - Defined without @entity directive- Missing field: id: ID!`

Do you know any example subgraphs that support grouping?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

field id is mandatory,

try this

```
type Aggregated{
  id: ID! 
  field: String!
  value: String!
}
```